# A value of type 'x' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T'

Tags: dart

Given the following code I don't understand why the error `A value of type 'Foo' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T'.` is thrown.

```
void main () {
  Bar bar = Bar();
}

class Foo {
  //
}

class Bar<T extends Foo> {
  T foo = Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why the error `A value of type 'Foo' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T'.` is thrown.

`T extends Foo` means that `T` is substitutable for `Foo` (every instance of `T` is also a `Foo`), not that `Foo` is substitutable for `T`.

`T foo = Foo();` is unsafe because `Foo()` isn't necessarily a `T`; `T` could be some other class that derives from `Foo`.  For example, suppose you had:

```dart
class Baz extends Foo {
  void someBazSpecificMethod() {}
}
```

now if you used `Baz` as `T`, that would be equivalent to `Baz foo = Foo();` which clearly should be illegal.

Answer (score -1):

Just cast the type and you should be good to go:

```
void main () {
  Bar bar = Bar();
}

class Foo {
  //
}

class Bar<T extends Foo> {
  T foo = Foo() as T;
}
```

I cannot explain the idea behind this in detail, but that's related to Dart's type system being nominal - you can't assign an instance of supertype to a subtype.

Comment: This is a runtime error if `T` is ever *not* equal to `Foo`.

Comment: Well my example is a bit biased for the sake of simplicity. So in this exact example I guess this could be unsafe.
But truth is I am using Flutter and I ended up doing this exact solution, it is actually perfectly working for my use cases.